# What is the "household members" number in the New York birth index?

Tags: birth-records, ancestry.com, new-york-city

On Ancestry they have a search of the birth record index for New York City. One of the data fields is called "household members" and it has a long number. What does this mean? Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Can you do a keyword search on that number? If so, what happens? Can you browse back to the beginning of a year and see what material is on page 1? Is there a column that says "Household members" on the image itself?  I don't see anything like it on this sample at NYG&B: https://www.newyorkfamilyhistory.org/blog/new-nyc-birth-index-images-1910-1965-available-ancestrycom or this sample at VitalSearch. 
http://www.vitalsearch-ca.com/gen/ny/samples/vs/nyc/NYnycbi949sample1.htm